# Curious Warning Message on UITextView

Tags: ios, warnings, uitextview, nib

Has anyone run across this warning message building for the iPhone?
More importantly do you understand how to fix it?

"unsupported configuration data detection and editable"

It's seems to be the UITextView that is complaining.
Here's a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I have hit this too. No solution as yet. This is very worrying though!

Answer (score 71):

The problem is that you have that textview set both to editable + to detect/autolink phone numbers, events, addresses, etc. a text area can either be editable and not detect/autolink text, *or* it can autolink text but not be editable.

Your settings for that textview should look like:

[image]

or

[image]

but not like:

[image]

Comment: Why It couldn't be editable and Detect Links, Addresses and Phone Number? I didn't find an answer for it.

Comment: I can't find a reason in the documentation, but my understanding is that it's simply unsupported to be both editable and recognize links etc

Answer (score 2):

I think in your scenario, the text input is only used to input text, nothing more. Then when it get's presented back, the "presenting text view" will take care of detecting the potential information... dates, events, etc.

To be more precise : in a simple app scenario, a user types in some text (let's say an event input text view - with no detection necessary at this point). Then when it get's eventually presented back to him or another user (let's say the detail view of the event), the text will be presented back in a "non-editable" text view that in turn will be able to have detections.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a little old, but this is how I resolved it;

In Interface Builder I have Links Detection **selected**, and Editable Behaviour **not selected**.

Then, in my ViewController, I implemented the UITextView `- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView { }` delegate method and `return NO`.

It removed the warning and prevents the user from being able to edit the UITextView's content.